# Countdown function not working correctly in timeout block

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval, countdown

I can't get the second countdown function to work correctly in the first Snippet. I fire off cdtd(); a second time for that. Both cdtd(); functions do not collide and are in inside anonymous functions. When I fire off cdtd(); the first time I get a working countdown timer until 16:00:00. When I fire off it for the second time I will not get a working countdown timer until 17:00:00. This is the actual use case of this question.

Just to made an example flow I made a second snippet. Both cdtd(); do collide eachother but the second cdtd(); function call will give a working countdown timer back. Now I still don't know why it's not working in the first snippet. Havint there a timeOut function I work with.

I'm not sure what is wrong. Anyone has got a clue?

Here is the script. https://jsfiddle.net/3fq2j6a1/

I tried to run the countdown scripts under eachother and that works but I don't need that :) `function cdtd() { .. }`

Here is a snippet:

```js
// First session

var sessie1 = new Date();
var totsessie1 = new Date(sessie1.getFullYear(), sessie1.getMonth(), sessie1.getDate(), 14, 16, 0, 0) - sessie1;
if (totsessie1 < 0) {
  totsessie1 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
}
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "Message.";


  // First countdown

  function cdtd() {
    var now = new Date();
    var dolazak = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 16, 0, 0);
    var timeDiff = dolazak.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
    }
    //if(minutes < 2){document.getElementById(id).style.color="#ff0000";};
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds to go!";

    timer = setTimeout(cdtd, 1000);
  }

  cdtd();
  // End first countdown

}, totsessie1);

// Second session
var sessie2 = new Date();
var totsessie2 = new Date(sessie2.getFullYear(), sessie2.getMonth(), sessie2.getDate(), 14, 17, 0, 0) - sessie1;
if (totsessie2 < 0) {
  totsessie2 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
}
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "Message.";


  // Second countdown

  function cdtd() {
    var now = new Date();
    var dolazak = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 17, 0, 0);
    var timeDiff = dolazak.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
    }
    //if(minutes < 2){document.getElementById(id).style.color="#ff0000";};
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds to go!";

    timer = setTimeout(cdtd, 1000);
  }

  cdtd();
  // End second countdown

}, totsessie2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<span id="time"></span>
```

Here is the snippet of the code when I use the countdown scripts under eachother.

```js
function cdtd() {
  var now = new Date();
  var dolazak = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 15, 0, 0);
  var timeDiff = dolazak.getTime() - now.getTime();
  if (timeDiff <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
  }
  //if(minutes < 2){document.getElementById(id).style.color="#ff0000";};
  var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
  hours %= 24;
  minutes %= 60;
  seconds %= 60;

  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " min and " + seconds + " seconds to go! (countdown to line 49)";

  timer = setTimeout(cdtd, 1000);
}

cdtd();

function cdtd() {
  var now = new Date();
  var dolazak = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 16, 0, 0);
  var timeDiff = dolazak.getTime() - now.getTime();
  if (timeDiff <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
  }
  //if(minutes < 2){document.getElementById(id).style.color="#ff0000";};
  var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
  hours %= 24;
  minutes %= 60;
  seconds %= 60;

  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " min and " + seconds + " seconds to go! (countdown to line 49)";

  timer = setTimeout(cdtd, 1000);
}

cdtd();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<span id="time"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/edfcLzhw/

But I need them inside the session blocks. When doing that I will get a different time left with the second countdown timer. `totsessie1();  totsessie2();`

The countdown script comes from: [Javascript countdown defined with hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560244/javascript-countdown-defined-with-hours)

Comment: Your code should be presented *in* the question, not behind a link. And when you do, please only present the *minimal* code necessary to reproduce the problem. So strip it of anything that is not needed to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Because of the nature of the question it is very difficult to past only certain code. This is because the second countdown timer only works if all code is posted. Also the session setTimeout functions do only work if I give all the parts of the code. I tried to insert the full code here while using ctrl-k and pasting it but it did get messed up a little bit.

Comment: Read the guidelines. Make sure that code occurs between two lines that each have three backticks. As it is JavaScript you can also create a runnable snippet in your question, using the toolbar. Sorry, but your question must have all relevant information inside it, not behind a link.

Comment: I now used snippets trincot. Thanks for the explanation. Hope it will become more clear this way by working more according the guidelines. The only downside of this is that the time given in the examples of the snippets can't be changed this way as long it is static code. In the jsfiddle it is changeable.

Comment: Your code defines two functions with the same name, which means only the second function will be defined. You should at least use distinct names for your functions. Could you describe (in your question) what exactly is the intended behaviour? We cannot know what "running correctly" means to you when we don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes I know. The second function is the one that can overwrite the first one. That is the actual goal. It fires off the second time within the setTime out code block on a different pregiven time. But the problem is that it not uses the right cowntdown time when doing that. Without that blocks within the second snippet it does give the correct cowntdown time. But as you know I need it in the first snippet to work.

Comment: @trincot the functions with the same name are inside anonymous functions, they don't collide

Comment: @vanowm, in the first snippet, but not in the second?

Comment: @vanown, that is right, but how come it will not give a correct countdown time on the second session (when it fires off the second time)? it will give a correct coontdown time on the first session: till it becomes 16:00:00 but on the second not till it becomes: 17:00:00. The second snippert is not relevant really. It is just an example flow about that it works. Even if they collide.

Comment: Please note that functions with the same name (in the second snippet) overwrite each other even before any statement is executed, so the first version is never called. But: can you edit your question and explain there the intended behaviour? If the second snippet is not relevant, then please remove it. People will keep pointing to its problems. If that is not your problem, better remove it, and instead explain in detail the expected behaviour.

Comment: @grid, the second  `totsessie1` is set for 17:00:00 (...`sessie1.getDate(), 14, 17, 0, 0) - sessie1`)...what is the problem?

Comment: @trincot, I did edit the initual forum post.

Comment: @vanown, the problem is that the second session will not couwntdown until 17:00:00. I made a type and did edit the function name of the second timeout block now to totsessie2();. But the problem is that it still doesn't work this way. This is why I came with this post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a description of the desired behaviour in your text. Just describe without reference to the code: Something like "I expect this and this to happen at 16:00, then I want this and this to happen at 17:00, ...". Currently I don't understand why you start two countdowns, when you only have one container in your page to show a countdown (one). Maybe you only want to start a second count down after the first has finished, but I cannot find that specification anywhere in your question.

Comment: @trincot, is this clear enough? The answer.

Comment: You do understand how `setTimeout()` work? you are set a delay in milliseconds, so whatever number your `totsessie1` has is how long the delay will be.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for now. I did not make the code correctly on 2 points.
First thing. I used the function totsessie1() also being the second totsessie1() function. I changed the second to totsessie2(). I also didn't use clearInterval(timer); before running the second cdtd();.

Here is a working snippet of the end goal:

```js
// First session

var sessie1 = new Date();
var totsessie1 = new Date(sessie1.getFullYear(), sessie1.getMonth(), sessie1.getDate(), 15, 25, 0, 0) - sessie1;
if (totsessie1 < 0) {
  totsessie1 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
}
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "Message.";


// First countdown

function cdtd() {
    var now = new Date();
    var dolazak = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),16,0,0);
    var timeDiff = dolazak.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
    }
    //if(minutes < 2){document.getElementById(id).style.color="#ff0000";};
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds to go!";

    timer = setTimeout(cdtd, 1000);
}

cdtd();
// End first countdown

}, totsessie1);

// Second session
var sessie2 = new Date();
var totsessie2 = new Date(sessie2.getFullYear(), sessie2.getMonth(), sessie2.getDate(), 15, 26, 0, 0) - sessie2;
if (totsessie2 < 0) {
  totsessie2 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
}
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "Message.";


// Second countdown

clearInterval(timer);
function cdtd() {
    var now = new Date();
    var dolazak = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),17,0,0);
    var timeDiff = dolazak.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
    }
    //if(minutes < 2){document.getElementById(id).style.color="#ff0000";};
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds to go!";

    timer = setTimeout(cdtd, 1000);
}

cdtd();
// End second countdown

}, totsessie2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<span id="time"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwvk8h12/

Comment: your `totsessie*` are not functions, they are variables containing a number.